# Django Forms - Declarative Fields Meta class is not iterable

Tags: django, django-forms

Why django throws me an error `TypeError at /primary argument of type DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass is not iterable`.

I'm trying to work with `django-forms` for the first time, after i added this into my `forms.py` file, it keeps showing me the error message saying: `TypeError at /primary argument of type 'DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass' is not iterable`, how can i solve this problem?

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Primary, PrimaryAlbum, Secondary, SecondaryAlbum
from jsignature.forms import JSignatureField
from jsignature.widgets import JSignatureWidget

class PrimaryForms(forms.Form):
    signature_of_student = JSignatureField(
        widget=JSignatureWidget(
            jsignature_attrs={'color':'#e0b642', 'height':'200px'}
            )
            )

    class Meta:
        model = Primary
        fields = ['admission_number', 'profile_picture', 'first_name', 
        'last_name', 'gender', 'address_of_student', 'class_Of_student', 'signature_of_student']
```

**Views.py**

```
from .forms import PrimaryForms

class CreatePrimaryStudent(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Primary
    fields = PrimaryForms
    template_name = 'create_primary_student_information.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Home')

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['year_of_graduation'].queryset = PrimaryAlbum.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(CreatePrimaryStudent, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by changing it from `fields = PrimaryForms` to `form_class` in `views.py` file under `CreatePrimaryStudent` class, and for `forms.py` file, I change the class method from: `class PrimaryForms(forms.Form):` to `class PrimaryForms(forms.ModelForm):`

**forms.py**

```
class PrimaryForms(forms.ModelForm):
    signature_of_student = JSignatureField(
        widget=JSignatureWidget(
            jsignature_attrs={'color':'#e0b642', 'height':'200px'}
            )
            )
    
    signature_of_guardian = JSignatureField(
        widget=JSignatureWidget(
            jsignature_attrs={'color':'#e0b642', 'height':'200px'}
            )
            )
     class Meta:
        model = Primary
        fields = ['admission_number', 'profile_picture', 'first_name', 
        'last_name', 'gender', 'address_of_student', 'class_Of_student', 'signature_of_student']
```

**Views.py**

```
class CreatePrimaryStudent(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Primary
    form_class = PrimaryForms
    template_name = 'create_primary_student_information.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Home')

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['year_of_graduation'].queryset = PrimaryAlbum.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(CreatePrimaryStudent, self).form_valid(form)
```

[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/)